# How to render form_rest() as hidden fields in Symfony2/Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, hidden-field

I have a Form class that contains many fields. I would like to render few of them and pass the left ones as hidden. How is this possible ?

I would like to do something like `{{ form_rest(form, {'display': 'hidden'}) }}` or `<div display="hidden">{{ form_rest(form) }}</div>`.

Example :

```
<form action="{{ path('fiche_intervention', {'rreid': rre.rreid}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div class="bloc-input">{{ form_label(form.rredatecommencement, "Date de retrait :") }}
    {{ form_widget(form.rredatecommencement) }}
    </div>

{# Some other fields... #}
    {# ... #}
{# /Some other fields... #}     

    <div display="hidden">{{ form_rest(form) }}</div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it in you buildForm function, inside the "FormController". Just adding 'hidden' when you add the field is enough.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('email', 'email');
    $builder->add('subject');
    $builder->add('anyone', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: and PéCé : You are both right, and I realize that I will have to create two form classes, each for one form.

Answer (score 3):

Also you may set all your unneeded fields as rendered in your twig template:

```
<form action="{{ path('fiche_intervention', {'rreid': rre.rreid}) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<div class="bloc-input">{{ form_label(form.rredatecommencement, "Date de retrait :") }}
{{ form_widget(form.rredatecommencement) }}
</div>
    {% do form.unneededfield1.setRendered %}                  
    {% do form.unneededfield2.setRendered %}                  
    {% do form.unneededfield3.setRendered %}                  
<div display="hidden">{{ form_rest(form) }}</div>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

form_rest() renders all non-rendered fields from your form. It just renders them as they are, so if you want to render remaining fields as 'hidden', you just have to define them as 'hidden' in your Form !

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

It's from the [official documentation (v3.0)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-rest-view-variables) so it's pretty much best practise i guess.